# How to off wave animation at the end of listview and scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

How i can off wave animation at the end/start of listview/scrollview

[image: this one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line in to RecyclerView layout

`android:overScrollMode="never"`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a Style:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:scrollViewStyle">@style/ScrollViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ListViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>

<style name="ScrollViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.ScrollView">
    <item name="android:overScrollMode">never</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManitest.xml**

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
        ...
>
```

**Or**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   ....
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre API level 14:

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

API level 14+:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
```